# how can i store my player's Playlist in Android programmatically

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sqlite

I am building a music player and i want to store my playlist even after my app is closed and retrieve back when app get started.
I am now able to get playlist in Array List.
please help..

Comment: Thank you for help but error occurred on this link.please send another if any..

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: Thank you Anirudh I will read this and try to apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save something when the app is closed override onPause method inside your activity or fragment then save the playlist from the ArrayList maybe in sqlite database, a file or a sharedpreference.
To retrieve it write your code in onCreate method then you can retrieve the saved data.

I didn't deal with sqlite but here you are a sharedpreference code if you wanna

```
class Playlist {
    private final String fileName = "myPlaylist";
    private SharedPreferences myPlaylist;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor myEditor;

    Playlist() {
        myPlaylist = getSharedPreferences(fileName, 0);
        myEditor = myPlaylist.edit();
    }

    public void save(ArrayList<String> mySongs){
        // Save the size so that you can retrieve the whole list later
        myEditor.putInt("listSize", mySongs.size());

        for(int i = 0; i < mySongs.size(); i++){
            // Save each song with its index in the list as a key
            myEditor.putString(String.valueOf(i), mySongs.get(i));
        }

        myEditor.commit();
    }

   public ArrayList<String> load() {
        // Create new array to be returned
        ArrayList<String> savedSongs = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Get the number of saved songs
        int numOfSavedSongs = myPlaylist.getInt("listSize", 0);

        // Get saved songs by their index
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfSavedSongs; i++) {
            savedSongs.add(myPlaylist.getString(String.valueOf(i)));
        }

        return savedSongs;
    }
}
```

sorry if the code contains mistakes but i didn't test it. Hope it helps